# TypeError generated when using inplace operations on numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, typeerror

If I run the following code:

```
import numpy as np

b = np.zeros(1)
c = np.zeros(1)
c = c/2**63

print b, c
b += c
```

I get this error message:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'add' output (typecode 'O') could not be coerced to provided
output parameter (typecode 'd') according to the casting rule ''same_kind''
```

If I change `b += c` to `b = b + c`, the code runs fine. Why is it so? I am running Python 2.7.2 on RHEL.

NumPy version: 2.0.0.dev-a2a9dfb

GCC version: 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post your numpy version (`print np.version.version`) and your `gcc --version` (from the shell), as we need the info for the bug report.

Comment: I similarly had this problem with `/=`. Thanks for your post solving it.

Answer (score 22):

When you do `c=c/2**63`, `c` gets casted to `dtype=object` (that's the problem), while `b` stays with `dtype=float`.

When you add a `dtype=object` array to a `dtype=float`, the result is a `dtype=object` array. Think of it as `dtype` precedence, like when adding a numpy float to a numpy int gives a numpy float.

If you try to add the `object` to the `float` *in place*, it fails, as the result can't be cast from `object` to `float`. When you use a basic addition like `b=b+c`, though, the result `b` is cast to a `dtype=object`, as you may have noticed.

Note that using `c=c/2.**63` keeps `c` as a float and `b+=c` works as expected. Note that if `c` was `np.ones(1)` you would wouldn't have a problem either.

Anyhow: the `(np.array([0], dtype=float)/2**63)).dtype == np.dtype(object)` is likely a bug.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a bug. Maybe -- but `2 ** 63` is larger than the maximum value of an `int64`, so I'm not sure it makes sense for `numpy` to do anything other than store it in an array of Python objects.

Comment: Except that a `long` has lower precedence than a `float`.

Comment: Yeah, and I can't even reproduce the OPs problem anyway.

Comment: @senderle Interesting: what version of numpy are you using?

Comment: `numpy 1.5.1`. But also, this still happens for me: `>>> (np.array([1], dtype=np.float) / np.array([2 ** 63]))` => `array([1.08420217249e-19], dtype=object)`. So I'm pretty unsure about what's going on now.

Comment: Seems like my version of `numpy` returns an array of `object`s for `b + c` but silently coerces the result to an array of `float`s for in-place assignment. (Which come to think of it is what I would expect.) I think the OP's behavior is related to new casting functionality, added in [versions 1.6 and 1.7](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#ufunc) (and possibly later).