# I'm trying to run this python script but It gives me errors related to sympy

Tags: python, python-2.7, sympy

Hi I'm trying to run this code using python I've installed the required modules but It give me this output:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sweep.py", line 62, in <module>
    Bb_all = zeros((3,0))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sympy\matrices\dense.py", line 1260, in ze
ros
    return cls.zeros(r, c)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sympy\matrices\dense.py", line 521, in zer
os
    r = as_int(r)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\compatibility.py", line 406, in
 as_int
    raise ValueError('%s is not an integer' % n)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

The code's Github: https://github.com/kai5z/Chladni-patterns

Comment: Post all relevent code here directly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is on these lines:

```
Bb_all = zeros((3,0)) # line 62
Bs_all = zeros((2,0))
```

Sympy [documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/matrices/matrices.html#sympy.matrices.dense.zeros) says:

> sympy.matrices.dense.zeros(r, c=None, cls=None)[source]
>
> Returns a matrix of zeros with r rows and c columns; if c is omitted a square matrix will be returned.

So remove the `()` and it should work (there are multiple instances where you pass a tuple parameter to `zeros` -> `zeros(3,0)` so be sure to fix them all)

Comment: I did your answer but I got this: `Element k- and m-matrix symbolic evaluation done
Element k- and m-matrix numeric evaluation done
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sweep.py", line 123, in <module>
    F[loc_glob[el_i][a]] += f[a]
TypeError: ufunc 'add' output (typecode 'O') could not be coerced to provided ou
tput parameter (typecode 'd') according to the casting rule ''same_kind'' `

Comment: @I-Log see https://stackoverflow.com/q/12588986/3462319 or google it, this is a new bug

Comment: Thank you @depperm I managed to fix the script, It runs very well now, thanks again.

Comment: @I-Log if this fixed your problem please mark this as the right answer