# Fixing TypeError in Sklearn Model

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, typeerror

I've used `sklearn`'s `linear_model.Ridge()` numerous times. However, this time I got this error when fitting the model:

`TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' output (typecode 'O') could not be coerced to provided output parameter (typecode 'd') according to the casting rule ''same_kind''`

I believe the error has to do with the `sample_weights` data type. Below is my code.

```
X = df[['X']]
Y = df[['Y']]
weights = df[['Wgt']]
weights = weights.values
weights = weights.ravel()
lr_rg = linear_model.Ridge(alpha=2700)
lr_rg.fit(X, Y, sample_weight=weights)
```

Is something wrong with the weights set up? I have done a similar set up for the model previously and never had any trouble. Fitting the model without `sample_weights` works perfectly.

I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588986/typeerror-generated-when-using-inplace-operations-on-numpy-arrays) but couldn't figure out how to apply it to my problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? What does weights look like?

Comment: @MaximeKan the weights are just a numpy array. `X` and `Y` are both pandas data frames.The documentation for `linear_model.Ridge()` calls for these data types so I am confused by the type erro.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the answer was that somewhere in the process the `weights` numpy array got the data type `object` when it needed to be `int64` for the `sklearn` model. Thus I added the following line of code before building the model:

`weights = weights.astype(np.64)`